# Is this the correct way to sort ptr_vector?

Tags: c++

I am trying to use boost's pointer container, and apply STL algorithms to it. I wrote a piece of code to sort a `ptr_vector<Point>` in which `Point` is a class with members `int x, y`. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_list.hpp>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct Point {
int x, y;
  Point(int xx, int yy) : x(xx), y(yy) {
   cout << "Point: " << x << " " << y << endl;
  }
 ~Point() {
  cout << "~Point: " << x << " " << y << " this: " << this << endl;
 }
};

struct ComparePoint{
 bool operator() (const Point& p1, const Point& p2) {
  return (p1.x + p1.y < p2.x + p2.y);
 }
};

struct PrintPoint{
 bool operator() (const Point& p) {
  cout << p.x << " " << p.y << endl;
 }
};
int main() {
 boost::ptr_vector<Point> v;
 v.push_back(new Point(1,3));
 v.push_back(new Point(2,0));
 v.push_back(new Point(3,4));
 v.push_back(new Point(4,1));

 //sort(v.begin(), v.end(), ComparePoint());
 for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), PrintPoint());
 return 0;
}
```

You may notice that I comment line "sort(v.begin(), v.end(), ComparePoint())", in this case the output (cout) looks normal, as follows.

```
Point: 1 3
Point: 2 0
Point: 3 4
Point: 4 1
1 3
2 0
3 4
4 1
~Point: 1 3 this: 0x1d3f010
~Point: 2 0 this: 0x1d3f050
~Point: 3 4 this: 0x1d3f030
~Point: 4 1 this: 0x1d3f070
```

However, when I uncomment the line "sort(v.begin(), v.end(), ComparePoint())", the cout output is as follows:

```
Point: 1 3
Point: 2 0
Point: 3 4
Point: 4 1
~Point: 2 0 this: 0x7fff3f723970
~Point: 3 4 this: 0x7fff3f723960
~Point: 3 4 this: 0x7fff3f723970
~Point: 4 1 this: 0x7fff3f723960
~Point: 4 1 this: 0x7fff3f723970
2 0
1 3
4 1
3 4
~Point: 2 0 this: 0x1e45010
~Point: 1 3 this: 0x1e45050
~Point: 4 1 this: 0x1e45030
~Point: 3 4 this: 0x1e45070
```

According to the output, the sort is ok, but there are extra 5 times of destructor calls. Where is that from?  More interesting thing is, if I change sort to stable_sort, the output is as follows:

```
Point: 1 3
Point: 2 0
Point: 3 4
Point: 4 1
~Point: 2 0 this: 0x7fffcbe85140
~Point: 4 1 this: 0x7fffcbe85140
~Point: 2 0 this: 0x26010c0
~Point: 1 3 this: 0x26010c8
~Point: 1 3 this: 0x26010d0
~Point: 1 3 this: 0x26010d8
2 0
1 3
4 1
3 4
~Point: 2 0 this: 0x2601010
~Point: 1 3 this: 0x2601050
~Point: 4 1 this: 0x2601030
~Point: 3 4 this: 0x2601070
```

From the output it seems two instances of Point are released from stack, other 4 from heap. I am afraid to use algorithm on pointer container because of this strange behavior? do you know how to explain this or is this the right way to sort ptr_vector or other sequential pointer containers?

Comment: If you are going to use printing technique to see what happens to objects you need to cover all the constructors (event the ones that are generated by the compiler) otherwise you will see the destruction of objects that look like they were never created (because you don't see the copy construction or the move construction or the assignment).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are using `std::sort` for sorting which would swap elements and thus cause calls to destructors. [`boost::ptr_containers` documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html#algorithms) states "*Unfortunately it is not possible to use pointer containers with mutating algorithms from the standard library. However, the most useful ones are instead provided as member functions:*". If you invoke `ptr_vector.sort()` instead I suspect you would see no calls to destructors.

Comment: What about std::stable_sort?

Comment: @dhardy Any std algorithm that moves elements will reallocate contents of ptr_vector. This may be ok depending on your needs. If however you need to avoid reallocation and still want to use std algorithms that have no analogous member functions then consider using vector of unique_ptr instead.

Comment: No, in my use case reallocation is not okay. I can't use `unique_ptr` because I'm still using C++98. So probably I have to use `vector<T*>` with manual memory management... leaks are in any case unimportant in my case since cleanup only happens at program exit and does not do anything besides freeing memory.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `boost::ptr_vector` in particular. `std::sort` sorts stuff by reassigning values utilizing temporaries. It's these temporaries that get destroyed and whose destructor calls you see.

As for why `std::stable_sort` destroys some of the dynamically allocated objects... I have no idea.

Comment: What I don't understand is this: the ptr_vector stores pointers to elements, so I would expect the _pointers_ to be copied not the elements itself. Could you help clarify this issue?

Comment: @nabulke: The pointer containers don't expose the pointers, they expose references.

Comment: Yes, during sort there are many swap and copy, but why the the times of constructor is less than that of destructor according to the cout?

Comment: @Richard: This is adequately answered in the comments on the other answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort` operates by swapping or moving the elements referenced by the iterators passed into it.

You did not specialise `swap` for `Point`, and so the default `std::swap` is used, which creates temporary objects. You are seeing the destructors for these temporaries.

Comment: The problem is why the times of constructor is less than destructor. I think the constructor should also be invoked even when creating tempory instance, right?

Comment: Because the temporaries are made using the (default) copy constructor, not the constructor that you defined.

Comment: The temporaries are created using the copy constructor `Point::Point(Point const &);` which is autogenerated and does not print a message.

Comment: The number of constructions _is_ the same as the number of destructions. You are only printing output from the `Point(int xx, int yy)` constructor, but not the `Point(Point const&)` and the `Point(Point&&)` constructors, and so you do not see some of the constructions.

Comment: @Mankarse, thanks, now I get it. A good lesson to remember copy constructor:-)