# How to sort boost::ptr_vector without changing element pointers

Tags: sorting, boost, c++11

I have an algorithm that stores elements in boost::ptr_vector. It is important for the algorithm that once allocated pointers to elements would not change until ptr_vector is destroyed. On the other hand I need to sort ptr_vector. I assumed (may be naively) that since regular std::sort swaps elements it will simply swap the order of pointers inside of ptr_vector without new and delete. On the other hand I see in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697339/is-this-the-correct-way-to-sort-ptr-vector) indications that sorting ptr_vector may actually change element pointers. Can someone confirm that reallocation actually happens? Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

I now think that my fears may **not** be justified. It seems that [the post that prompted my concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697339/is-this-the-correct-way-to-sort-ptr-vector?lq=1) referred to standard library sort which indeed would cause swapping and reallocation of elements. But ptr_vector has a member function implementation of sort and I have every reason to expect that it preserves element pointers and avoids reallocations.

Answer (score 0):

The pointervector, as a container, is obviously being sorted.

Had you wanted to retain all iterators and element references valid, you should be using

- boost::stable_vector
- or possibly some combination of/with boost multi-index

Sadly (?) I don't think there is currently anything that combines the two concepts. Of course such a thing can be written, and then `Boost Intrusive` could be highly instrumental to manage the implementation.